# How to display a HTML page in an ASP.NET Site.Master page

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

Please forgive the question if it is an obvious one, but I am new to web development and it has me stumped.

I have a website that has been developed using ASP.NET and it has a Site.master page which all of my other asp pages are displayed in.  I have downloaded a copy of VisualLightBox which generates an HTML page to display an image gallery.

So what I need to know is:

1. How do I get the HTML page to display in the MainContent part of the Site.Master, or
2. How to change the HTML to be part of an ASP.NET page

If there are other threads that give me the answer could you point me in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Site.Master page defines ContentPlacholders so that pages which inherit from the Site.Master can easily place their content in a unified layout. There is a good discussion of using a [Site.Master in the ASP.NET quick start tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/masterpages/default.aspx).

That said, you have several options for utilizing your HTML page along with your Site.Master. Much of the HTML rendered by [VisualLightBox](http://visuallightbox.com/) is boilerplate in that you do not have to use it. You simply need to extract the sections of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS that are important and restructure those in an .ascx or .aspx page. You can then use your Site.Master to link to the .aspx page or place the .ascx user control on the Site.Master.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you just create an .aspx page with your HTML?